# How to send wso2 esb error message or exception to my client

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I provoke an error in wso2ESB in order to have control in the client of some errors, while the esb console displays:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.EntitlementMediator} -  Error occurred while evaluating the policy {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.EntitlementMediator}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
...
...
```

the client console displays:

```
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI
```

I'm seeing different errors in consoles, I need to take the esb error message so that the client code can catch the same error esb

At this moment i have my sequence 'fault' configured like this:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="fault" trace="enable">
   <makefault version="soap12">
     <code xmlns:soap12Env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" value="soap12Env:Receiver"/>
     <reason xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
   </makefault>
   <send/>
</sequence>
```

and a sequence in sequence to my proxy service configured like this:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="InSequence" trace="enable">
   <entitlementService remoteServiceUrl="https://localhost:9443/services/" remoteServiceUserName="srxxx" remoteServicePassword="kiytr">
      <onReject/>
      <onAccept/>
      <advice/>
      <obligations/>
   </entitlementService>
   <header xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" name="wsse:Security" action="remove"/>
   <send/>
   <drop/>
</sequence>
```

I've tried several ways to get the error in my client without success if anyone can help me I would appreciate so much

Comment: Does your exception happens at the reception or during the send (inside the sequence)?

Comment: The exception happens inside the sequence, in my sequence there is a entitlement mediator which try to authenticate in the  wso2 identity server with the UserName and the Password specified, of course this user doesn't exist in the identity server, so the exception occurs

Answer (score 1):

Configure a faultSequence inside your proxy service as shown in below. In your case you have to use the fault mediator inside the faultSequence.

```
<faultSequence>
    <makefault version="soap12">
        <code xmlns:soap12Env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" value="soap12Env:Receiver"/>
        <reason xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
    </makefault>
    <send/>
</faultSequence>
```

For more information needed for sending the error message to the client use following documentations

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Error+Handling+and+Error+Codes

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Fault+Mediator